# Karate - Reading data from json file and assing it to a dynamically generated request

Tags: karate

I have following data.json file:

```
{
  "ids": {
    "id": "a2mx8m6yvksgu3605c7c1a61d"
  },
  "second": {
    "name": "test2"
  },
  "third": {
    "name": "test3"
  }
}
```

I did fetch a variable for the id from the json.

```
* def id = data.ids.id
```

I want to use this variable id (defined above) to a request.
Request defined below is dynamically being sent to the xml file i.e xml request is being generated with  but the below doesnt work when i try to pass the variable id.
This however works when i hardcode the id value.

```
* def ARG = {attr:  [ { regex: '#(ids)',  value: '<id>"#(id)"</id>'} ] }
```

Please help me how can i pass the data being read from json to the above line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

```
* def id = 'foo'
* def val = '<id>' + id + '</id>'
* def arg = { value: '#(val)' }
* match arg == { value: '<id>foo</id>' }
```